# angular 4. Fail to open application

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I try to open my angular app and recieve following error : [image]

I've tried to reinstall node modules, clean npm cache, but it didn't help. URL is localhost:4200

Code from app.component.html

```
    <app-global-loader *ngIf="isLoading"></app-global-loader>
<main [class.menu-collapsed]="isMenuCollapsed" baThemeRun>
  <div class="additional-bg"></div>
  <app-header-component *ngIf="showMenu"></app-header-component>
  <app-content-component></app-content-component>
  <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
</main>
```

Comment: CODE CODE CODE :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Code from which component?

Comment: Try to delete and reinstall webpack and clean cache

Comment: @SevastsyanOseev you can start with `app.component.html`